# What does "<>" exactly mean in "echo <> temp.txt"?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

#### Non existing file

```
$ ls file_not_exists.txt
ls: cannot access file_not_exists.txt: No such file or directory
$ echo <> file_not_exists.txt

$ ls file_not_exists.txt 
file_not_exists.txt
$ cat file_not_exists.txt
$
```

#### File with content

```
$ cat temp.txt 
asdf
$ echo temp.txt 
temp.txt
$ echo <> temp.txt 

$ cat temp.txt 
asdf
```

If the file does not exist, `echo <> file_not_exists.txt` will create a new file. So I think `>` works (redirecting the empty output into a newly created file). But if there is something in the file (like `temp.txt`), why it is not emptied by `echo <> temp.txt`?